# Need to commit after each 500 rows deleted

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sql-delete

I am invoking delete queries in a loop using JDBC. The number of records that are going to be deleted by a particular delete query is not consistent. It can be 40, 80 or 100 etc. My scenario is I need to commit after each 500 records deletion.

The way I implemented is, I am accumulating the count of the records that are going to be deleted by the particular delete query, until the count is equal or more than 500. As soon the count becomes equal to or more than 500, I am pausing count accumulation and invoking the delete query and committing to delete 500 records in one shot.
Is there any other better approach or JDBC standard way to do this?

Comment: "*I need to commit after each 500 records deletion*" - why do you think you "need" that? And which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using oracle. The reason why I need this is: there is a limit imposed in our production database that we can delete or insert or update only 500 records in one shot because this modification is cascaded to our back up database. This limit is there to avoid performance hits because we deal with billions of customer data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two JDBC APIs for deleting: You can run a query like `delete ... where PK in (...)` and pass an array of 500 primary keys. Or you can use JDBC batch to batch a series of SQL queries and run them as one.

Batch is just a way to package several SQL queries in a single "conversation" with the database. The performance gain is mostly network: Instead of sending hundreds of small packages, you send a few big ones. Parsing and processing on the DB side is the same.

But if you do a more complex query and collect the number of changed rows, then there is no special JDBC support for that. You have to accumulate the count yourself and then `commit` manually when the count gets too big.